# How to force remote desktop connection to maximise and reset resolution

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I am having trouble with my Remote Desktop connection not maxmimising on Windows 7 since I am using a different monitor. It seems like the connection has remembered the size of my old monitor and is attempting to maintain that screen resolution.

I can't maximise the remote desktop, there are always scroll bars. Is there anything I can do about this? I have tried disconnecting and reconnecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you launch Remote Desktop Connection without clicking on a remembered resource, you can Show Options - under the Display tab, shown there, you can set the resolution used.

I'd recommend (if it's on full-screen now) to set it to a low resolution (lower than current monitor), connecting, quitting, setting the resolution to Full Screen and reconnecting.